# Check multiple Values in a single column for the same reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have some rows like this:

```
Table: Orders
OrderNumber     City
------------------------
1001            Austin
1001            Dallas
1001            Houston
1001            Miami
1002            Austin
1003            Austin
1003            Dallas
```

I'd like to extract all OrderNumbers that have City as Austin **AND** any of the other cities. In the above example, I should get the orders 1001 and 1003 but not 1002.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
select *
from orders o1
where o1.city = 'Austin'
  and exists (select ordernumber
              from orders o2
              where o1.ordernumber = o2.ordernumber
              group by ordernumber
              having count(distinct city) >1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3187d/5)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible approach would be to have two CTE (Common Table Expressions) - one for all `Austin` order, another for all other orders - and join those on the `OrderNumber`:

```
WITH AustinOrders AS
(
    SELECT OrderNumber FROM Orders WHERE City = 'Austin'
), OtherOrders AS 
(
    SELECT OrderNumber FROM Orders WHERE City <> 'Austin'
)
SELECT
    DISTINCT ao.OrderNumber
FROM AustinOrders ao
INNER JOIN OtherOrders oo ON ao.OrderNumber = oo.OrderNumber
```

Produces the result of:

```
OrderNumber
-----------
   1001
   1003
```